# How to define patterns to filter lists of replacement rules?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a list of replacement rules like

```
list˘of˘replacement˘rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

and I want to filter all the elements where ‘b’ is replaced by using Cases[] and a search pattern.
The following code does not work:

```
Cases[list˘of˘replacement˘rules, b -> _]
```

The result is {}.
How should the pattern be defined in order to get the result {b->2}?

Comment: `Cases[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}, HoldPattern[Rule[b, _]]]`

Comment: This question was “put on hold” because it appears to be a simple mistake. But I don’t think so. I truly searched the documentation for a solution before posting this question. You just have to **know** about the existence of certain keywords like HoldPattern[] or PatternSequence[]. Otherwise you would not find them in the documentation.

Comment: Very closely related but not about ***patterns***: [(69299)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69299/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};

FilterRules[rules, b]
(* {b -> 2} )*
```

or

```
Cases[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}, PatternSequence[b -> _]]
(* {b -> 2} )*
```

Comment: FilterRules is particularly practical since you may also use it with a rule b->something, even blank as second argument or with a list of such rules. In this case, it does not care for the rhs of those rules.

Answer (score 11):

[`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) handles an expression with head [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) specially, providing replacement functionality, therefore you need to keep the literal head of your pattern from being `Rule`.  Examples:

```
Cases[rules, _[b, _]]
Cases[rules, x : (b -> _)]
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[b -> _]]
Cases[rules, Verbatim[Rule][b, _]]
```

All evaluate to `{b -> 2}`.  None of the patterns have the head `Rule`:

```
Head /@ {_[b, _], x : (b -> _), HoldPattern[b -> _], Verbatim[Rule][b, _]}
```

> ```
> {_, Pattern, HoldPattern, Verbatim[Rule]}
> ```

Of course for this particular operation [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html) is more direct.

Comment: Isn't this a better place? And isn't this topic a duplicate? [69299](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69299/5478). Moreover, what's up with @kglr 's memory? :)

Comment: @Kuba It would be nice if people would close things as duplicates when they are duplicates, rather than "easily found in the documentation."  I am starting to think that even having that close reason is a mistake, as the same simple questions are asked repeatedly anyway.  In this case I saw a closed question, noted the OP's comment, and agreed.

Comment: @Kuba No, wait x 2.  (lol)  That one is about `Select` and this is about `Cases`, and while kglr answered both with an alternative the direct answer is different.  I am going to leave this open after all.

Comment: I don't mind the order, I'm ususaly trying to link to the best topic so it will be linked in more places.

Comment: Good point (2nd lol).

Comment: @Kuba I cannot disagree with that, but I know I got my feelings hurt once when my older question was closed as a duplicate of a newer one and I haven't forgotten that, so I always tend to favor the older question.