# Select a particular rules out of a list

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, rule

```
rule = {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2, x -> 4, z -> 2, w -> 0.8}
Select[rule, beta]
Select[rule, beta &]
Select[rule, beta -> _ &]
```

How would I select the rule that applies to `beta` only?

Or more general, how to select the rules apply to `alpha` and `beta` (or more variable, but not all of them)?

Thanks.

Comment: Closely related: [(65892)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65892/121)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also use [FilterRules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html):

```
rule = {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2, x -> 4, z -> 2, w -> 0.8};

FilterRules[rule, beta]
(* {beta -> 4} *)

FilterRules[rule, {beta, alpha}]
(* {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2} *)
```

**Update:** additional alternatives if you have V10:

```
KeyTake[rule,{alpha, x}]
(* or *) KeyTake[{alpha,x}][rule]
(* <|alpha->2,x->4|> *)
Normal@KeyTake[rule,{alpha, x}]
(*  {alpha->2,x->4} *)

KeySelect[rule, MatchQ[#,alpha|x]&]
(* or *) KeySelect[MatchQ[#,alpha|x]&][rule] 
(* <|alpha->2,x->4|>  *)
Normal@KeySelect[rule, MatchQ[#,alpha|x]&]
(*  {alpha->2,x->4} *)
```

Comment: Yeah, I certainly need more sleep...

Comment: @Kuba Why?  Your method is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Nice use of `KeyTake`.  That one isn't in my repertoire yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. Added to my _repertoire_ a minute ago:)

Comment: Warning: `KeyTake` will by nature return only one rule for each key: `KeyTake[{a -> b, b -> c, c -> d, b -> 2}, b]` yields `<|b -> 2|>`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, do we need a similar warning for `KeySelect`? (I am getting the message "You have exceeded the session memory limit for your plan"  when i try to run `KeySelect[MatchQ[#,b]&][{a -> b, b -> c, b -> 2}]` on the free wolfram programming cloud).

Comment: @kguler that appears to hang in a Notebook as well.

Comment: @kglr, how to pick composite key patterns, eg given `{{a, x} -> 1, {b, y} -> 2}` how to pick {a,x}? Whether as is or wrapped in Key[{a,x}], neither KeyTake or FilterRules matches.

Comment: @alancalvitti, `FilterRules[{{a, x} -> 1, {b, y} -> 2}, HoldPattern@{a, x}]` works in versions 9 and later and  `KeyTake[{{a, x} -> 1, {b, y} -> 2}, {{a, x}}]` works in version 11.

Answer (score 7):

```
Select[rule, MemberQ[{beta, alpha}, #[[1]]] &]
```

Answer (score 6):

V9 style

If `rule` is a simple list of rules:

```
Cases[rule, _[beta | alpha, _]]
```

> ```
> {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2}
> ```

---

other ways to go:

```
{beta, alpha} /. (# -> Rule[##] & @@@ rule)
```

Comment: First approach is simple to understand. second approach looks more complicated though.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Take a look at `(# -> Rule[##] & @@@ rule)`

Comment: @kuba I am trying to replicate your first solution as follows: Cases[rule, Rule[beta | alpha, _]] but it did not work. do you know why? this works fine Cases[{{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {c, 5}}, List[a | b, _]]

Comment: @Algohi `Rule` makes `Cases` think that you want to replace `beta|alpha` with `_`. Since by default `Cases` works on level `{1}` it can't find anything anyway. To make use of explicitly stated `Rule` you need `HoldPattern[...]`

Answer (score 5):

One more method using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) and [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html):

```
Pick[rule, Keys@rule, alpha | beta]
```

> ```
> {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Rule[#, (Association@rule)[#]] & /@ {beta, alpha}
```

> {beta -> 4, alpha -> 2}