# How to match Association[]?

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

The following input:

```
Cases[{"key" -> Association[]}, HoldPattern["key" -> Association[]]]
```

Returns `{}`. Why does it not return `{"key" -> Association[]}`? I was expecting it to match.

Comment: You should use `Verbatim` for that. `HoldPattern` is for patterns

Comment: @RunnyKine I thought I would use `HoldPattern` to treat the rule itself as a pattern, otherwise the rule is interpreted by `Cases` (as discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112333/pattern-matching-for-rules/112335)

Comment: The subtle point here is that `Association[]` evaluates to `<||>`, and even though the `FullForm`s of the two are the same, `SameQ` on them gives `False`, because the constructor `Association[]` does a non-trivial job when evaluated, and the result of it is *not* a normal expression `Association[]`, but a new atomic object.  So, we have `Unevaluated[Association[]] === Association[]` producing `False`. Therefore, `MatchQ[Association[], HoldPattern[Association[]]]` gives `False`, while of course `MatchQ[Association[], HoldPattern[Evaluate@Association[]]]` gives `True`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: very interesting. I keep forgetting `Association` is an atomic expression.  But how would you suggest I do the matching with `Cases`? Inspired by your `MatchQ` example I can see that `Cases[{Association[]}, HoldPattern[Evaluate@Association[]]]` matches, but it won't match if the expression containing `Association` is a `Rule`. For instance: `Cases[{"key" -> Association[]}, 
 HoldPattern["key" -> Evaluate@Association[]]]` won't match.

Comment: Use `Verbatim`, as @RunnyKine suggested. Since it does not prevent evaluation of parts of the pattern, you will then compare evaluated / constructed `Association[]` in your expression with a similarly evaluated `Association[]` inside the pattern. Or, much simpler, if you don't care whether or not association is empty, you could use `_Association` pattern, which is matched in both cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer the question of why there is no match let's look at the output of `Trace`:

```
Cases[{"key" -> Association[]}, HoldPattern["key" -> Association[]]] // Trace

(* {{{{Association[], <||>}, "key" -> <||>, "key" -> <||>}, 
  {"key" -> <||>}}, Cases[{"key" -> <||>}, HoldPattern["key" -> Association[]]], {}} *)
```

We see that `Association[]` gets evaluated to `<||>`, which as Leonid states is not a normal expression and so will not match `Association[]`.
As I suggested in the comments, I think the right approach in this and similar situation where an evaluation might occur with `Association[]`, is to use [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html):

```
Cases[{"key" -> Association[]}, Verbatim["key" -> Association[]]]

(* {"key" -> <||> } *)
```

If you look at the `Trace` of the expression, you'll see why it matched.

```
Cases[{"key" -> Association[]}, Verbatim["key" -> Association[]]] // Trace
```

`Verbatim` allows its input to also evaluate, hence both expressions now look the same: `"key" -> <||>`, hence the match. 
Finally, if for some reason you really want to use `HoldPattern`, then I suggest wrapping your expression in `Unevaluated`:

```
Cases[Unevaluated[{"key" -> Association[]}], HoldPattern["key" -> Association[]]]

(* {"key" -> <||> } *)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is quite clear now.

Comment: @paideia. You're welcome, glad I could help clarify things.

Comment: Just wondering: how to match `_ -> Association[]` (using `Unevaluated` is not an option)?

Comment: @paideia. `Unevaluated` works for me. `Cases[Unevaluated[{_ -> Association[]}], 
 HoldPattern[_ -> Association[]]]`