# Using Cases for lists containing Rule ( -> )

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to extract an expression of given pattern from the list of the form

```
list = {a -> b, c -> d} (* typical output of Solve *)
```

For example, all the expressions which look like `x -> 0`.

For obvious reasons, `Cases[list, _ -> 0]` does not work. What should I do instead?

Comment: I'd say 90% methods there make it a good duplicate? Do you agree? [65892](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65892/5478), another related: [3916](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3916/5478)

Comment: This is literally the only example listed under "Possible issues" for `Cases`. Close as "easily found in the documentation".

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I agree that this is easily found in the documentation for `Cases` but I think this question is more useful to the community marked as a duplicate than simply closed, so I did that.  I do not mean any disrespect to you by this action.  If you feel that my action was inappropriate please tell me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, duplication is an important mechanism, if only for the fact that so many don't bother reading the documentation. On a meta-note, I got a feeling that this QA is rep-farming: trivial Q, immediate textbook A... I'd make a meta post, but applying Hanlon's razor is easier.

Answer (score 9):

`HoldPattern[]` solves the problem!

`Cases[list, HoldPattern[_ -> 0]]`

Comment: You can also use `Pattern`: `Cases[{a -> 0, b -> 1}, s : (_ -> 0)]`. -- And `Verbatim[Rule][_, 0]`, etc.

Comment: I think the answer should be `Verbatim[Rule][_,0]` as that is the construct especially made for such cases. The others are just working for this particular case "by accident" but are meant for different use cases...

Comment: "The others are just working for this particular case "by accident" but are meant for different use cases". How do you conclude that? The documentation for `HoldPattern` specifically mentions the use case `Cases[{a -> b, c -> d}, HoldPattern[a -> _]]`.